# Setup QGIS with local plugin repository only

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, repository

Is there a best practice how to setup QGIS without the official repository but only with a local repository?

The idea behind this is to setup a stable environment where local GIS-admins check plugins before they are added to the local repository.

We had some issues with plugins that made our QGIS installations unstable (for example https://github.com/vinayan/RectOvalDigitPlugin/issues/6 ). As reliablity of software is more important to our colleagues than the free choice between 800 plugins we want to preselect the plugins that are available for them.

At the end of the day it's probably not possible for the person who has to setup QGIS installations to prevent that users install some unwanted/unstable plugins as the plugin-directory and the QGIS2.ini has to be writable by the users but we still want to make our QGIS-working environment a bit more stable.

My ideas are:

- Removing the local repository and making the "add" button invisible?
- Blocking the official repository through the proxy?
- using a Whitelist for allowed plugins and checking the installed plugins against the whitelist with a plugin installed in the QGIS-program folder?

Has anyone else made some experience with QGIS setups in a business IT infrastructure?

Comment: and to be clear, this is in a Windows environment? Was QGIS installed on all the machines with the OSGeo4W installer?

Comment: @SaultDon yes, windows and installed with the osgeo4W

Comment: We're talking about the plugin repository specifically I think? You're not asking about repositories of QGIS software in general? It might be helpful to put that in the title.

Comment: @Rostranimin: done

Comment: What is your problem now? Your ideas are good. Do you have a challenge of implementing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it doesn't seem to be possible to prevent users from installing unwanted/bad plugins I have setup a plugin which waits for the initializationCompleted
signal and checks the installed plugins against a whitelist with qgis.utils.available_plugins. So I can at least inform the user that he uses a plugin that has not been whitelisted yet:
[image]