# Where can I find the source code of the "QGIS Python Plugins Repository"?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Along the lines of [this (unanswered) question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282557/setup-qgis-with-local-plugin-repository-only), where can I find the **source code of the QGIS Python Plugins Repository website** - or the source code of the software driving this infrastructure?

The [QGIS website](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Website) itself is a static website. The [QGIS Web Client 2](https://github.com/qgis/qwc2) also does not appear to be what I am looking for - please correct me if I am wrong. I am basically looking for the QGIS counterpart to [Warehouse](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse).

Comment: I don't undertand your question,but if you want find the oficial qgis repor is this .xml  https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

Comment: @FranciscoRaga `plugins.xml` is just the result of one of many possible queries against a much larger database I presume. There is software behind it, enabling users to upload plugins, review plugins, managing storage, manage user accounts (authentication) etc. - a somewhat larger and complicated web application. Where can I find its source code?

Comment: i'm not sure but this project https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Django maybe

Comment: @FranciscoRaga that looks like it (in /qgis-app/plugins), could you put this in as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

based in my comment.

Go to this project Django project for QGIS related activities such as plugin repository

[github.com/qgis/QGIS-Django](http://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Django)